# Flutter how to set margin for particular widget in a form

Tags: flutter

// here is my main.dart file

```
class UserRegistrationPage extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
  UserRegistrationPageState createState() => UserRegistrationPageState();
 }

 class UserRegistrationPageState extends State<UserRegistrationPage>{

   @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        body: new SingleChildScrollView(
          child: new Container(
            child: new Form(
              child: formUi(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
        );
  }
  Widget formUi(){
    return new Column(
       children: <Widget>[
        new Image(
                image: new AssetImage("assets/bgtopbar.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
         new TextFormField(
                  //  margin: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
           decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Mobile Number'),
           keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
           maxLength: 10,
         ),
         new TextFormField(
           decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'First Name'),
           maxLength: 20, 
         ),
         new TextFormField(
           decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Last Name'),
           maxLength: 20,
         ),
         new TextFormField(
           decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Gender'),
           maxLength: 10,
         ),
       ],
    );
  }
```

I want to set margin only the edit text field in the form i don't want to set for image.How can i give margin for individual widget in a form.i know this question is very simple but i am new to flutter so help me to sort out this problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create below method and set margin as you want

```
Widget allTextFieldWithMargin(){
    return Container(
    margin: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0), // Or set whatever you want 
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new TextFormField(
            //  margin: new EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Mobile Number'),
            keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
            maxLength: 10,
          ),
          new TextFormField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'First Name'),
            maxLength: 20,
          ),
          new TextFormField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Last Name'),
            maxLength: 20,
          ),
          new TextFormField(
            decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Gender'),
            maxLength: 10,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
   }
```

And call **allTextFieldWithMargin** method like belwo

```
 Widget formUi(){
    return new Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Image(
          image: new AssetImage("assets/bgtopbar.png"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
       allTextFieldWithMargin()
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Hello @Govaadiyo, please help me understand why are you no longer using `Form` in your example.

Answer (score 4):

You can wrap it in `Container`

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
  child: yourWidget,
);
```

UPD:

If you want to set only horizontal margins - you can organize widgets like:

```
Column
  Image
  Container
    Column
      TextFormField
      TextFormField
      TextFormField
      TextFormField
```

Comment: if i give inside the container margin will be set for all widgets in the form

Comment: i dont want to set margin for an image.i want to set margin only for the text fields

Comment: And this is what I said. Put all `TextFormField`s in `Column` and wrap this `Column` in `Container` with margins